# Is there a good way to align divs, images etc equally within a div without having to use class .first?

Tags: css, layout, css-float, html

I hope my question made sense.

I'm wondering if there is a good way to align divs without having to use a class to distinguish the left div, so that the browser knows no to add any left margin to that div?

Say if you have a 3 column portfolio:

each column has a:

```
.column300 {
float:left;
width:300px;
margin-left:20px;
}
```

Then you set the first column to have a class of .first and no left margin:

```
.column300.first {
margin-left:none;
}
```

and so on.

So the 1st, 4th, 7th, 10th etc columns would all have class .first added to them, so things line up nicely.

---

I was just wondering if there is a better way of lining things up in these situations? Perhaps so that you don't have to add the class of .first to each left column.

It's really for when you are designing for say a portfolio layout that is going to be controlled by CMS, whereby adding a class of .first to every left column may prove difficult.

Any thoughts or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: the pseudo first-child? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_firstchild.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have many `div` elements next to each other with the class `.column300`.  If that is the case, try the following CSS code.

```
.column300:nth-child(3n-2) {
     margin-left: none;
}
```

You can test it with "`3n-2`" in the [:nth-child tester](http://css-tricks.com/examples/nth-child-tester/).

Comment: ahaa... I remember hearing about this now... Basically this is a way of telling say every 4th element and giving it a margin-left:none; I'll look into this more :)

Comment: This seems like a nice way of getting things cross browser: http://verboselogging.com/2010/01/17/making-nth-child-work-everywhere

Comment: @ade123, thanks for the cross browser info.  Did I answer your question completely?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a CSS Framework?! 
Try the 960grid @ http://960.gs/

Comment: I have been looking at the 960grid framework recently. It looks interesting, but not sure if I like the idea of using a css framework, as I've always been in favour of the flexibility of hand coding. Maybe something to consider though... :)

Comment: you'll not say that after really using it :D